# check-in process (fb, 4sq, g+) for a mobile app

Tags: android, objective-c, facebook, foursquare, google-plus

I would like to make an app which would allow users to post check-ins at one place to all their social networks at once.

Can I check-in a user via back-end server not directly from an app?

I mean, 
- user registers her social network credentials in the app (fb, 4sq, g+) => auth tokens are obtained and sent to the server.
- user taps check-in button in the app. 
- app sends user's location details and the check-in request to the backend server, and server posts check-ins on the user's behalf on all social networks the user has registered. These should be exactly check-ins not just wall posts.

Sorry, if that's a dumb question. I'm not a developer myself, i'm just writing TOR. I've searched extensively, but couldn't get a definitive answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You could but going about it gets ... complicated...

Comment: Each social platform will have a very different answer and implementation. It would probably be better to ask for details on each individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to check in a user from your server. If a user has authorized your app, you can use their OAuth token to perform actions (such as check in) on their behalf. See http://developer.foursquare.com for more information on performing actions via the API.